# UINotification selecting from handleActionWithIdentifier display specific viewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, notifications

I am new to iOS programming and I only understand swift language for now. For my app, I have set up user, local and remote notifications. The local notifications have 2 actions, 1 to dismiss and the other is to direct the user to a specific viewController.

My viewController hierarchy to the specific viewController I want to display is tabBarController -> (2nd tab) tableViewController -> (one of the many tablecells) viewController

After Richard's suggestion, I have simplified my code with the above hierarchy. I have performed a background fetch to my server in response to a remote push notification and save content locally before creating a local notification to inform the user. I have managed to set up to the point where I guide the user to the correct Tab on the tabViewController using `self.window?.rootViewController.selectedIndex = 1` within `application:handleActionWithIdentifier` in App delegate.

How do I proceed with selecting the correct tablecell assuming that the local notification holds an index that can be used?

Edit: 
After some tinkering, I managed to get the viewController I wanted to be displayed.

```
if var tabb = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
       tabb.selectedIndex = 1
       var controllers = tabb.childViewControllers
       for controller in controllers {
           if let navcon = controller as? UINavigationController {
                    if let tblvc = navcon.childViewControllers.first as? QuestionnaireTableViewController {
                        tblvc.becomeFirstResponder()
                        tblvc.moveUserToQuestionnaire(questionID)
                    }
                }

            }
        }


func moveUserToQuestionnaire(questionID : String) {
    var list = questionnaireObj.getQuestionnaireListData()
    for item in list {
        var selected = item["questionnaire_id"] as! NSString as String
        if selected == questionID {
            selectedUserID = item["study_id"] as! String
            selectedReplyBatchID = item["reply_batch_id"] as! NSNumber
            selectedQuestionnaireID = questionID
            performSegueWithIdentifier("SelectQuestionnaire",sender:self)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

If this is a correct method to use, please inform me. Thanks! Hope it also helps someone in the process. =)

Comment: I don't understand most of your post, but looking at your view controller hierarchy, I would suggest a start by simplifying your storyboard by making the tab bar controller the root view controller. Your loginViewController can be presented modally on top of the tab bar controller when the user needs to log in.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I thought of presenting the loginViewController modally as you have mentioned. I will do some tinkering before asking again.